# What's the best way to get a Scala Object field by inputting Object name in String

Tags: scala

I know it's basically either using latest scala reflection API in 2.10 or using the hacking way to use Java reflection API on generated Java class. But I searched around but cannot find the right solution I need as I would like to input a String representing an object name and then get certain field value of that object.

---

Also I found the following hacking works , but it's not as elegant as using the pure reflection API as suggested by Sergey

```
object Object1 {
    val x: List[Int] = List(1,2,3)
    val y = 2
  }

  val rm = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)  
  val module = rm.staticModule("some.package.Object1")  
  val obj = rm.reflectModule(module)
  val im = rm.reflect(obj.instance)

  val f = Class.forName("gretter.Object1$").getDeclaredField("x")
  f.setAccessible(true)
  val x = f.get(obj.instance)
  println(x.toString())
```

Comment: What is your use case? Scala really emphasizes static typing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Print all `val`'s from `object` by name (including `private` and `private[this]`):

```
        val className = "some.package.SomeObject"

        import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}
        val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

        val moduleSymbol = mirror.staticModule(className)
        val moduleMirror = mirror.reflectModule(moduleSymbol)
        val instanceMirror = mirror.reflect(moduleMirror.instance)

        val fields = moduleSymbol.typeSignature.declarations.filter(_.asTerm.isVal)
        for (f <- fields) {
            val fieldMirror = instanceMirror.reflectField(f.asTerm)
            println(s"${f.name}: ${fieldMirror.get}")
        }
```

If you need particular field value, you can find it by name in `fields`.

Comment: Thanks! This works as I am originally looking for 'typeSingature' and not want to use the 'typeOf[T]'. 

I actually want the following.

`val field = moduleSymbol.typeSignature.declaration(universe.newTermName("x")).asTerm.accessed.asTerm;
        val fieldMethod = im.reflectField(field);
        println(fieldMethod.get);`

Comment: with scala 2.13.8 this gives me `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: MODULE$`